# Why Class.forName("Test").getClassLoader()?

Tags: java, classloader

why do `getClassLoader()` needs to be called using `Class` object ?? why can't I simply call `getClassLoader()` using the object of any class present in that package ?? for instance why cant i simply get which `Classloader` loaded my class using `(new Test()).getClassLoader()` ?

Comment: I would say because **Class**Loader loads **classes, not objects**.

Comment: @BackSlash - Well, *theoretically*, `getClassLoader()` is being called on *Class Object* of `Test` class :)

Comment: As Suggested by BackSlash ClassLoader can be obtained by Classes only. but if you want the ClassLoader using current class you can use *Test.class.getClassLoader()*  or  *Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()*

Comment: @TheLostMind Here is the trick: It's a specific type of object, an object of type `Class` :)

Comment: @BackSlash - I understand your point :). I am merely saying that the first comment *incompletely* answers the OPs question.. The second, however completes it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to differentiate between classes and objects.

```
Test t = new Test()
```

Will produce an object. If you want the classloader of it, you need to access the class of the object because a classloader loads classes, not objects. Let's say

```
ClassLoader cl =  t.getClass().getClassLoader();
```

If you just want a reference to the classloader which loaded Test, you could also write Test.class.getClassLoader().

Answer (score 0):

as BackSlash wrote, the ClassLoader loads the class and is referenced in the class object. If it were referenced in the instances of the class, then this reference would be attached to everey object in the VM, enlarging the size of the objects. As the objects have a reference to their class object anyway, there's no need to duplicate the classloader reference in every object.